# Jekyll github-pages website does not display CSS formatting except locally

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

There are many questions similar to mine, but most of them arise from not using baseurl correctly. My [website](http://austinstover.github.io), however, does not even use a baseurl. It uses the root Github page. I essentially forked my website off of the Airspace theme ported by [luminousrubyist](https://github.com/luminousrubyist/airspace-jekyll), whose [website](https://luminousrubyist.github.io/airspace-jekyll/) displays correctly, so somewhere down the line I made a change that stopped it from displaying correctly. Therefore I would appreciate it if someone else could figure out what's wrong; I have been trying to figure it out for hours.

My Github [page](https://github.com/austinstover/austinstover.github.io)

My _config.yml file:

```
    title: "My Portfolio"
subtitle: "My portfolio, detailing my experience"
# Base URL of site. It should always start with a slash,
# and never end with a slash. Set it to a blank value if hosting at the
# root of your server.
# baseurl: "/" # the subpath of your site
url: "http://austinstover.github.io" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
cover: "/assets/cover.png"
logo: "/assets/logo.png"

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown

# Google analytics
ga_tracking_id: "UA-90009514-1"

# Category descriptions (for archive pages)
descriptions:
  - cat: jekyll
    desc: "Posts describing Jekyll setup techniques."

  - cat: dummy
    desc: "Just some placeholder posts, lorem ipsum and the rest."

exclude:
  - "/vendor/"
  - "Gemfile"
  - "Gemfile.lock"
  - "README.md"
  - "LICENSE.md"
  - "*.gemspec"

keep_files:
  - "CNAME"
  - ".git"
  - ".gitignore"
```

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that the front matter is displaying on your page, which means that it is not applying the templates. I would check the encoding / line endings of the files.

Answer (score 1):

try to set `baseurl` in your `_config.yml`:

```
 baseurl: "" #if not used.
```

btw, your index.html use `page.html`  layout (from `_layouts`), that use `default.html` layout which include `head.html` (from `_includes`). this one call `{{ site.baseurl }}` but it's undefined .

Comment: According to the [jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/), baseurl is set as an empty string by default, so I do not need to set it to an empty string; regardless, I have tried an empty string, a forward slash, etc. and none of these seem to get my page working.

Comment: I think you need to uncomment the baseurl too and leave it blank. My site and dev sites all have it and seem to work fine

Comment: this is what i think too, in a freshly created them, it may be left, as the OP mentioned, but since the theme they are using refers to this attribute {{ site.baseurl }} explicitly to locate the resources path it may cause some issue when removed. 
although I'm not sure, because I couldn't reproduce the problem ^^"

Comment: I should mention that the website displays correctly when I use `bundle exec jekyll serve` to publish the site locally- it only displays incorrectly on Github Pages.

Comment: I also tried changing the name of my repository to "mywebsite" so that I could add the baseurl `/mywebsite`, but that did not get the website to display the formatting either, so it definitely isn't a problem with the baseurl.

Comment: if it display correctly locally but not on github page then check the list of pluging, github run your site in safe mode, thus, disabling all the plugin not white listed [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-jekyll-plugins-to-a-github-pages-site/) ( and here is an [updated list](https://learn.siteleaf.com/themes/jekyll-plugins/) ).

Comment: and check that you list properly all the plugin present in your `Gemfile` in the `_config.yml` under `gem: [plugin-1, plugin-2, ...]`

Comment: Was this ever solved? I have the exact same problem...